# What is the advantage of Dual-Band Wireless?

Tags: wireless-networking, router, dual-band

I've been looking around for a good wireless router, and I've been seeing a lot of dual-band routers, but everyone I've asked at the stores seems to give me a different answer as to what it actually does. So I'd like to ask the wireless gurus over here at SU, what are the advantages and disadvantages to using the cliche dual-band wireless routers?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

802.11b and 802.11g both use the same frequency band, 2.4Ghz. 802.11n can also use the 5Ghz frequency band. By using this area as well as 2.4 you get more available channels, so potential for less interference. Also in the 5Ghz band 802.11n uses channels which are twice as large, which increases the speed.

Therefore a dual-band wireless router, which is 802.11n enabled, will give you faster bandwidth, less interference, and better reliability.

Comment: +1 however, this is the theory, i found that in practice with 5GHz the range is signifacantly shorter than with 2.4 GHz. and to take full advantage of dual-band technology, of course the clients must support 5GHz as well. a good Wireless N router suits me just fine.

Comment: Thanks for the info! Superuser comes through with a W again :)

Comment: I should note that not all Wireless-N cards will pickup that 5Ghz signal. I found that out painfully while I watched my not-so-computer-savvy father reap the benefits of 5Ghz wireless while I was stuck on 2.4 Ghz.